# IdP Metadata & Certificate signing as SHA1 for ADFS

Tags: cryptography, saml-2.0, adfs

I am building as part of a custom IdP an endpoint to get SAML Metadata for a given service.

My goal is to import this metadata into ADFS when creating a **Claim Provider Trust**, and have it set to SHA1.

the **KeyDescriptor** element does not seem to let me specify how assertions will be signed (SHA1 or 256), and ADFS defaults then to 256.

Is there any way to set the public key to be understood as SHA1?

Comment: "the element does not seem to let me specify..." what is this "element"? A tag of the metadata file? Which one?

Comment: Typo with as making the element name hidden IU n markdown syntax :)

Comment: **KeyDescriptor** only has an EncryptionMethods list available, but doesn't seem to have any effect on the key declared as "signing"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know whether it is possible to modify this setting using metadata only.

I personnally set this setting via Powershell after having imported the metadata. My method is (both steps done using Powershell):

1. Create the trust using the metadata file.
2. Set all additional settings on the trust that were not set by the metadata.

Maybe you could do something similar.

Comment: I would have prefer to set everything properly from the first time, but it does not seem feasible after all, I'll be using powershell to do so, thanks!

Comment: You can do so with the following Powershell command: `Set-ADFSClaimsProviderTrust -TargetName "ClaimIdTrust" -SignatureAlgorithm "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"`

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can specify ADFS to use the SHA-1.

In the ADFS Management console right-click on the corresponding relying party ( Trust Relationships -> Relying party trusts -> select your relying party) and go to advanced tab. There you can select between SHA1 and SHA-256

[image]

Comment: I know this can be changed like this, the idea for me is to import metadata info and have this setting straight configured to SHA1, with no manual config changes